# Embarcadero and free opc ua

Tags: c++, plc, opc

I'm trying to get an app working with a PLC. I'm using this library: https://github.com/FreeOpcUa/freeopcua

example code: https://github.com/FreeOpcUa/freeopcua/blob/master/src/examples/example_client.cpp

But when I include the header files(like in the example) from the library it gives an error:

Non-Virtual function 'DateTime::DateTime(const DateTime &)' declared pure.

When I search the specific line of this error it shows me this:

```
    DateTime(const DateTime&) = default;
```

I already asked it on the github page, and they are saying it has something to do with my compiler. I never touched it, so it shouldn't be having odd options.

So how can I solve this? And if there is something wrong with my compiler, How can I change my compiler options to get it fixed?

[image]

Comment: You are lacking details, like which product of Embarcadero you are using in which version and such. In general, if your using e.g. C++Builder to create 32 Bit applications, it is safe to assume that there's no option to change, but the used compiler simply lacks the C++ features needed. C++Builder XE 10 has been published recently with a new 32 Bit compiler based on CLANG and LLVM, that may be worth a try.

Comment: Sorry about that, I'm using the  C++ builder XE8 32 bit. I can change some options for the compiler: I've added the screenshot in the question

Comment: @ThorstenSchöning There is no XE 10 and new Rad Studio has no XE prefix, it is just Rad Studio 10.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, bcc32 don't allow to create instance of abstract class. So you can change target platform to **win64** and compile without errors.

Another way, as Thorsten Schöning said, you can use C++ Builder 10 with bcc32c based CLANG compiler and do it also without errors.

Comment: I can't set it to win 64. I did something wrong when I was installing this program I guess? or should I update something? I am using a 64 bit OS so that shouldn't be the issue

Comment: You would have needed to install 64 Bit Windows support during installation, which is the default, and need to add 64 Bit Windows as target platform in the project. There's a context menü where your target platform is specified as 32 Bit Windows.